# Opening windows from other applications on a specific location

Tags: windows, hook, multiple-monitors, window-position

is it possible to force all Windows' windows (and windows from other applications) to open at a specific location? If yes, how?

Perhaps there is a way to force all programs to open windows "center screen" or at position xy.

Comment: I forgot to say that this would be in C++.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more efficient way, but one way this can be done is using [AutomationElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745106.aspx).

The machine running this will need to have a the automation api update installed [KB971513](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/search.aspx?q=KB971513) if its not running Windows 7

Comment: Thanks. Thats a .NET example. How about c++?

Comment: COM UIA with C++ [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winuiautomation/archive/2011/05/18/building-ui-automation-client-applications-in-c-and-c.aspx) 
[link2](http://www.code-magazine.com/articleprint.aspx?quickid=0810052&printmode=true) 
[link3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671406(v=vs.85).aspx) 
[link4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee684021(v=VS.85).aspx) 
[forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/threads) [Original StackOverflow Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7650826/858670)